# Mobile Image sizing

Tags: image, mobile

I've been working on a theme for the site http://silversoundz.com and have it looking just how my client wants it on browsers but the problem comes when I shrink the screen to check the site on mobiles, in particular the Iphone.

It seems like there's a minimum threshold (around 768px width) before the header+icon svg files go back to their enormous default dimensions thus rendering everything else tiny in relation to that. I've changed the icons to smaller pngs but I'm not sure what the best course of action is for resolving the header scaling/sizing so everything is proportional on a small screen.

Here's the problematic css

```
media="all"
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
.logo-img {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
position: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out:

Basically I just had to find the relevant bit of css which was only kicking in for screens > 768 and re-paste it below the general styles which says:

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

so it would come into affect for the general styles too.